# Verify a page in motion in selenium

Tags: java, testing, redirect, selenium, ui-automation

While redirecting from one page to another, a redirection page appears for 1-2 secs. How do I verify that redirection page? I tried to check for some element on that page and pause but that was not working.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

With Selenium [Explicit waits](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)

```
driver.findElement(By.id("redirect")).click();//click on some link which will get to to your page
WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
   .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("someElementOnTheRedirectionPage")));
//now you can assert elements atrributes
//now you are on the desired page after redirection
```

Comment: I tried this, but the page comes only for 2-3 seconds and reaches to next page.

Comment: And what is your problem?This code will wait until the redirect page appears and then continue, this is what you want, right?

Comment: I want to verify some elements on redirect page and then move to next page. but its directly going to next page and there it tries to find those elements on next page. Its not even finding a single element on redirect page.